# Python Requests - post json

Tags: python, json, sqlite, post, python-requests

POST CODE

```
import requests

form = {
    "token": 123,
    "discordid": 330421170186879007
}

data = requests.post('sample/dir', json=form)
```

Recieve CODE

```
@app.route('/dir', methods=['POST'])
def post():
    Discordid = request.form.get("discordid")
    token = request.form.get("token")
    cur.execute("UPDATE table SET Token = (?) WHERE DiscordID = (?);", (Discordid, token,))
    conn.commit()
    print(token, Discordid)
    return ('', 204)
```

and I get None and `None` for the print at the receiving console.

Why I getting `None` for the Discordid, token and How can I fix this?

Comment: try with `data = requests.post('sample/dir', data=form)` and maybe on `cur.execute("UPDATE table SET Token = (?) WHERE DiscordID = (?);", (Discordid, token,))` you need to change the order of the parameters?

Comment: I change the order thx and I fixed it!

Comment: Good. Could you please mark my answer, that I just posted, as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
data = requests.post('sample/dir', data=form)
```

and maybe on

```
cur.execute("UPDATE table SET Token = (?) WHERE DiscordID = (?);", (Discordid, token,))
```

you need to change the order of the parameters?

Comment: It was fine with working, but I had to use data form as json so I can't use it.
I tried with 
`content = request.get_json()
Discordid = content["discordid"]
token = content['token']` 
and it worked! thx